# Dynamic elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues regarding dynamically created elements. I'm trying to creating a page for my site which will display a list of users(which has been passed into my view from the controller). For each user i've created a div holder, and inside each div I have two h3 tags displaying both the ID and Name of the user. Each user div also contains a button, which allows a user to be hidden, or shown.

```
 <div class="single-user" id="@user.Hidden.ToString()">
     <h3>ID: @user.Id</h3>
     <h3>Name: @user.Forename @user.Surname</h3>
     <span><input type="submit" class="sub-btn" /></span>
 </div>
```

along with then 'name' and 'id' property I also pass in a 'hidden bool property. This is used to check if a user has been hidden. The problem i'm having is that because the elements have been created dynamically, they all share the same classe's and id's, so i'm unable to check if a user is hidden or not. I looked online and found a possible solutions, however, it's still not working. Here is my javascript code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $('.single-user').on('click', '.sub-btn', function () {
        if ($('.single-user').has('#True')) {
            console.log("true");
        }
        else {
            console.log("false");
        }
    });

 </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to wrap your script code inside `document.ready` (depending on where the script is)

Comment: `id` must be unique, even for dynamically-generated elements. Use another attribute, such as by having two class names or using a `data-` attribute.

Comment: .has(selector) looks for elements _inside_ the target element that fit the selector.  Your id is on the element itself so .has() is not what you want here.  As the others said you also don't want to use the id attribute in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="single-user" data-visible="@user.Hidden.ToString()">
     <h3>ID: @user.Id</h3>
     <h3>Name: @user.Forename @user.Surname</h3>
     <span><input type="submit" class="sub-btn" /></span>
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click', '.sub-btn', function () {
        if ($(this).closest('.single-user').attr('data-visible')=="True") {
            console.log("true");
        }
        else {
            console.log("false");
        }
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikola for the response, however, I get the following error message when I click on a button:

Uncaught TypeError: Object True has no method 'val'

Comment: @gb1986 I noticed that and I removed it val(), it seems that u have copied the code before have edited. Simply copy the current code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I copied the new code, but regardless of which button I click, the value 'true' is always printed to the console. I checked the values being passed to the view and there are a few users with the value 'false' for the hidden property. It seems like it's using the hidden value for the first user, regardless of which button is clicked. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: @gb1986 replace the if with: `if ($(this).closest('.single-user').attr('data-visible')=="True") {`